# Issues with input

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have created a script for adding Send on Behalf Perms for a DG on prem in a hyrbid environment but having a few issues with it processing the list of names. If you add one name its fine add another and it removes the old and adds the new. That is how it is. So the command you normally string the list of names separated by a comma then it will add them all and it works fine. The script allows me to list them however fails to find the entries. Can anyone suggest why or an edit which will make this work?

```
#Script prompts for the required information needed to perform the required actions. 
$Distro = Read-Host 'Insert Distribution Group to check perms.'
$DGroup = Read-Host 'Insert Distribution Group Name e.g. DG-Test@test.com'
$username = Read-Host 'Insert User who needs Send On Behalf. Please include all shown in the last step seperate each name by a comma. Format is First Lastname.'

#Displys the current settings for Send on Behalf rights for the DG.

Get-DistributionGroup $Distro | FL GrantSendOnBehalfTo

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to proceed to next step"

#Now script adds the required permissions input at the beginning.

Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo $username

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to proceed to next step"

#Now the script shows the current permissions after changes

Get-DistributionGroup $Distro | FL GrantSendOnBehalfTo

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Ideally i will look split so it displays the current perms then asks who needs adding so you can just add the names all within the script. I am new to this so still learning and looking to get one part done then expand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot test this myself, but from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps#parameters):

To add or remove one or more values **without affecting any existing entries**, use the following syntax:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add="$username", "$username2"}
```

---

Because you are using `Read-Host` it is vital to always check/correct the input you are getting. The prompt tells people to enter `First Lastname`, but to uniquely identify a mail-enabled user or group, it would be MUCH better to ask for either `SamAccountName`, `Emailaddress` or `UserPrincipalName`.

Because the input names can contain spaces or characters that need quoting, my suggestion would be to **always** quote whatever the user inputs.

Something like:

```
$prompt = @"
Insert user(s) that need Send On Behalf.
You can enter multiple usernames, separated by a comma.
Allowed names are SamAccountName, EmailAddress or user full name (Firstname Lastname).

"@
# get the (string) input from the user
$username = Read-Host $prompt
# as per your latest comment and testing, simply split the input on comma
# to create an array of names. (Trim to remove unwanted whitespace)
$users = ($username -split ',').Trim()
```

Then add these to the group with

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$users}
```

Needless to say that you should provide checks for everything you are receiving from Read-Host inputs, so also test if the given `$Distro` and `$DGroup` actually exist before doing anything with these values..

Comment: That fails. It doesn't like the input at all. If i paste the below 
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo $username

then add names name,name1,name2 then run in direct in PS then it works. Its just the script doesn't like the list when input it doesn't make the changes.

Comment: @Kevlar That then all depends on what the input looks like. Your prompt says to separate user names with a comma, but if the values contain spaces or otherwise require quotation marks, you need to quote each value. You should test for that in your code and not simply supply anything someone enters via Read-Host without knowing if input is valid or not..

Comment: Thank you. So the name input should have said firstname.lastname which is the sAMAccountName. I have tried your script and it fails also for multiple entries.

Manual entry to connect to PS then run the command it works just not when stringing them together in a script.

Comment: @Kevlar Do you get error messages when running from script? Is the script connecting? Is the script running with the same credentials?

Comment: @Kevlar The documentation is not very clear, but you could try using an **array** of users instead of a comma delimited string. [1] `$users = ($username -split ',' | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_.Trim() })` [2] `Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DGroup -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add=$users}`.

Comment: apologies, this virus takes all my time with sorting other issues.... Yes the script connects and the permissions commands work fine so it shows me the current permission's in place and that they remain. The new change throws me an error the user isn't found which is strange as hes there. So not sure what it is. the Bizarre thing is this works when manually in ps.

i get the below error
Couldn't find object ""Joe Bloggs"". Please make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.

now it appears to double quote it. Do you think that maybe the issue?

Comment: My above comment seemed correct the actual names were being double quoted so made the following change and it now works

$users = ($username -split ',' | ForEach-Object { '{0}' -f $_.Trim() })

So removed the "" in this part '"{0}"' 

Thank you @Theo

Comment: @Kevlar Thanks for testing this. I edited the code to not double quote the items in the array.